# Replacing image without influencing frame

Tags: android, layout, imageview

Here is a small gif of my current situation. I guess many images are better than many words.
[image: seekbar bug]

As you notice, when I switch for the smaller image, the seekbar size changes. I know this is because of the seekbar's width being set to `match_parent`and the image's width to `wrap_content`.

What I don't know is how to overcome this problem, as I can't really hardcode width value otherwise it'll probably get messed up on various screensizes.

So my question is :

Is there a way to prevent this behaviour that is clean? I could simply get the width at runtime and set it as minimal width and it would probably work (heck, I could try it now to make sure), but that is just a horrible thing to do code-wise.

Ideally, I'm guessing there is a way to prevent this in the .xml file, but I couldn't figure it out, playing with the different paddings, margins, scaling and layout sizes.

Here is what you're looking at :

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp">
        <ImageButton
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:id="@+id/playButton"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/play"
            android:onClick="PlayButtonClicked" />
        <SeekBar
            android:max="100"
            android:id="@+id/volumeSeekBar"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/playButton"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/muteButton" />
        <ImageButton
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:id="@+id/muteButton"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:onClick="MuteButtonClicked"
            android:src="@drawable/sound" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You could set an explicit width for your ImageButtons, or utilize weights (if you switch to linear layout) to your views to avoid it. For example, a LinearLayout with a weightSum of 10, each ImageButton having a width of 0dp and weight of 1 and the SeekBar having a width of 0dp and weight of 8, it would be less dynamic. You could also use a scaleType like centerInside in conjunction with this to make sure your images don't scale weird.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally it would be nice for the volume icons to be of the same size.

If that is not an option, try replacing `android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/muteButton"` with `android:layout_marginRight="15dp+30dp+largest_icon_width_in_dp"`
where 15dp is your seekbar right margin, 30dp is the mute button right margin.

The third option would be to set a fixed width for the mute button equal to the width of the largest image.